# Select from a table where fields don't match conditions

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm just wondering what kind of SQL command I could execute that would select all items from a certain table where column A is not equal to `x` and column B is not equal to `x`

Something like:

```
select something from table
where columna does not equal x and columnb does not equal x
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The key is the sql query, which you will set up as a string:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE NOT columnA = 'x' AND NOT columbB = 'y'";
```

Note that there are a lot of ways to specify NOT. Another one that works just as well is:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE columnA != 'x' AND columbB != 'y'";
```

Here is a full example of how to use it:

```
$link = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass) or die("Unable to connect to database");
mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die("Unable to select database $dbName");
$sqlquery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE NOT columnA = 'x' AND NOT columbB = 'y'";
$result=mysql_query($sqlquery);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
//do stuff
}
```

You can do whatever you would like within the above while loop. Access each field of the table as an element of the `$row array` which means that `$row['field1']` will give you the value for `field1` on the current row, and `$row['field2']` will give you the value for `field2`.

Note that if the column(s) could have `NULL` values, those will not be found using either of the above syntaxes. You will need to add clauses to include `NULL` values:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE (NOT columnA = 'x' OR columnA IS NULL) AND (NOT columbB = 'y' OR columnB IS NULL)";
```

Comment: Glad to help. I started off with the block of code as an example...then I edited like 10 times as I kept saving only to think "wait, I could add one more thing to make it that much clearer"

Comment: neither of these seem to work if column's default value is `NULL`

Answer (score 8):

You can use like

```
NOT columnA = 'x'
```

Or

```
columnA != 'x'
```

Or

```
columnA <> 'x'
```

And like Jeffly Bake's query, for including null values, you don't have to write like

```
(NOT columnA = 'x' OR columnA IS NULL)
```

You can make it simple by

```
Not columnA <=> 'x'
```

**<=>** is the Null Safe equal to Operator, which includes results from even null values.

Answer (score 3):

Or can also insert the statement inside bracket.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE NOT (columnA = 'x')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where fiels1 NOT LIKE 'x' AND field2 NOT LIKE 'y'
```

//this work in case insensitive manner

Answer (score 2):

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE columnA <> 'x' AND columbB <> 'y'";
```

I'd suggest using the diamond operator (<>) in favor of != as the first one is valid SQL and the second one is a MySQL addition.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers will not work if there's a null value.

Here's a shorthand to evaluate fields that can be null using coalesce:

```
select * from table where coalesce(my_nullable_field, 0) <> 1
```

Here we tell the query to treat NULL as a 0, without adding a completely other condition for nulls, which would keep wiring simple and the code easily readable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use also

```
select * from tablename where column1 ='a' and column2!='b';
```