# Mysql equivalent for "ne" or not equal perl

Tags: mysql, perl

Novice here. Sorry and thanks. I need to find records that don't equal 'Ok'. This code doesn't work.

Is there a MySql equivalent to Perl's `ne`?

```
use DBI;

SELECT * FROM people WHERE status ne 'Ok'
```

Comment: read the documentation on comparison operators: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/expressions.html

Comment: This is a **very** basic question readily answered by [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) as well as [many other sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+not+equal).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select from where field not equal to Mysql Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286644/select-from-where-field-not-equal-to-mysql-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ne operator in mysql is !=

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE status != 'Ok'
```

Comment: I wonder how it can be 'ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad' when Ian answered it? Thanks

Comment: @ta There were 5 votes to close. Only (2 or 3) was as "not a real question". One or two was as "duplicate" and another was as "not constructive". I would have voted as "duplicate" but others were faster.

Answer (score 5):

there are two operators for that

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE status != 'Ok'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE status <> 'Ok'
```