# How to display Status ERROR if sql columns has zero value?

Tags: php

I have this line of code, which checks the result of the query. I want to have a STATUS ERROR if one of the columns contains a value= '0'.

If the condition founds a zero value it will echo: Status: ERROR,

[Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF0pJ.png)

**PHP CODE**:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inventorybill_tbl`";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Failed".mysqli_error());

//Here it will check the result if there is a value contains zero                                                 
if (empty($result)) { 
echo 'Status: ERROR'; 
} else {
echo 'Status: OK'; 
}
?>
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  bool zeroExist = false;
  $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
  foreach ($finfo as $val) 
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      if ($row[$val->name] === 0)
      {
        zeroExist = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(zeroExist){
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!zeroExist){
    echo 'Status: OK'; 
  }else {
    echo 'Status: ERROR'; 
  }
```

try this

Comment: Uhm the status error will display sir if any of the values in table head contains a value zero.    EXAMPLE: twohundred: 0   then status : Error

Comment: just seven columns sir

Answer (score 0):

**mysqli_query() Return values**

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Check if `empty($result->num_rows)` - then there's no data.

Comment: its not the data for the status: error sir, its just the value if it contains a zero  value in any table columns, then it will display  error status.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //$row["your column name"]
        if (empty($row["twohundred"]) || $row["twohundred"]=='0' || $row["twohundred"]==0) { 
            echo 'Status: ERROR'; 
        } else {
            echo 'Status: OK'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check condition in your query instead of PHP code.

Rewrite your query as below:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT columnA = 0 OR NOT columnB = 0;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnA != 0 OR columnB != 0;
```

Check this [Original Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286644/select-from-where-field-not-equal-to-mysql-php)