# how can I select all records except where meeting_status.teacher_id not equal to a specific teacher

Tags: php, yii, phpmyadmin, reference

my first table is   meeting

```
id | title | body         | 
---------------------------
1  | mytit | my message   |
---------------------------
2  | anoth | another mes  |
---------------------------
3  | title | again a mess |
```

my second table is  Meeting_status and it has a foreign key from the meeting table and another table called teachers

```
status_id  |  teacher_id  |  meeting_id 
-------------------------------------------
  1        |   28         |     2         
-------------------------------------------
```

my query is :

```
SELECT * FROM meeting LEFT JOIN meeting_status ON meeting.id = meeting_status.meeting_id WHERE meeting_status.teacher_id <> 28
```

what I want as result is to show only the rows where teacher_id 28 doesn't exist like:

```
 id  |  title  |   body         | status_id  |  teacher_id  | meeting_id  
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  mytit  |  my message    |  NULL      |   NULL       |  NULL     
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 3   |  title  |  again a mess  |  NULL      |   NULL       |  NULL
```

Comment: This link should actually solve the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286644/select-from-where-field-not-equal-to-mysql-php

Comment: What is wrong with your same query?

Comment: it selects 0 outputs

Comment: you cannot do that either use `left join` and show all meetings with `NULL` values for the keys where no association exists in the `meeting_status`, this will show `meeting` which are against the `teacher_id =28` but will reflect `NULL`. or no meetings will be shown that have no association in `meeting_status`, that will ommit the teaacher_id 28 too

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM meeting
LEFT JOIN meeting_status ON meeting.id = meeting_status.meeting_id where(teacher_id IS NULL
OR teacher_id <> 28)
```

and it gave me the output I was expecting.