# filter multiple rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

```
Company   Year
--------------
AxisBank  2018  
AxisBank  2019  
AxisBank  2020  
ICICIBank 2018  
ICICIBank 2019  
ICICIBank 2020
```

Now I want to filter only Axis Bank and year less than 2020. So that output should be like below

```
Company   Year
--------------
AxisBank  2020  
ICICIBank 2018  
ICICIBank 2019  
ICICIBank 2020
```

Can someone please help me with Query

Comment: Your result and your question doesn't match. If you want to filter only AxisBank then why your output contains ICICIBank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from a table where fields don't match conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286644/select-from-a-table-where-fields-dont-match-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
where company <> 'AxisBank' or year = 2020
```

You can also express this as:

```
where not (company = 'AxisBank' and year < 2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use full Query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE Company != 'AxisBank' OR (Company = 'AxisBank' AND Year >= 2020)
```

So it will filter out, Company AxisBank and Year is less than 2020.